# Using NOT LIKE in Filter property of a VBA Recordset

Tags: excel, vba, sql-like, recordset

I am using Excel 2003 to connect to a SYBASE database using a VBA recordset. I want to filter the records.

The following is code I have used.

```
Dim rset As New ADODB.Recordset
rset.Open sQuery, m_db, adOpenForwardOnly
rset.Filter = "Name NOT LIKE 'Dav%'"
rset.Requery
```

But it is not working and returning all rows. If I use `Name LIKE 'Dav%'`, it's correctly returning records with `Name` starting with 'Dav'.

What is the problem with `Not LIKE`? Am I missing something?

Also, I need to use `Requery` to get the filter work. Is it really required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NOT keyword is not allowed in the filter property.

Comment: is there a `NOT` statement along with `AND`, `OR`, `LIKE` at all?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can include the NOT LIKE in the sQuery value.
Like:

```
select * from NamesTable where [name] NOT LIKE 'Dav%'
```